# Console errors serving google font Roboto over https

Tags: fonts, https

I've linked to Google's Roboto font in the header of our site with https, but I'm getting errors on our shopping cart page that I'm attempting to serve it over http.  Am I missing something?  I don't understand how it's not linking correctly.  Here is what I have in our header:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400italic,700italic,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And here is the page where I'm getting the error (you'll have to add something to your cart to get the errors to show up).

https://www.usalight.com/ShoppingCart.asp?

Comment: I've tried linking it this way as well to no avail:

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com.....etc.

Comment: pretty much ALL of your links to products are hard-coded to jump to plain `http://` links. wouldn't surprise me if you do have something trying to load http// content from an https// page.